# Is there a Interface Builder-esque way to get that slick "pull down to refresh" menu I see on the Facebook iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've seen this in other apps too, so I'm wondering whether there's some canned functionality I'm missing. Is there an interface for the "pull down to refresh" action? If not, what's that called so I can Google it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but for anyone ending up on this page - This feature is now built into iOS - Just do a search on stack overflow or the web for UIRefreshControl.

I believe if you are targeting iOS 5.0 or later, this is the way to go - Its also super easy to implement

Answer (score 5):

It is not built-in functionality but you can grab the open source version from the guys who originally implemented it :-)

http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Comment: Just make sure to give them credit and leave the attribution/license at the top of their source files :)

Answer (score 4):

No. You should look at [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for your submission. The other answer was slightly faster. Both were great.

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out the answers - you can make a table view in IB, put it in a view, and then change the type to be something like an EGOTableViewPullRefresh table.  Then you just set an outlet for it and implement the delegate methods in the view controller.

In fact I find it very handy to use table views as a subview of a view in a normal view controller.  The UITableViewController only provides a handful of convenience mechanisms.